# rails authlogic gem - destroy action error in UserSessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm using the Authlogic gem as the authentication system for a rails app. This is my code in the UserSessionsController

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'auth_layout'

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
 end

 def destroy
   current_user_session.destroy
   redirect_to new_user_session_url
 end
end
```

Although every time I type in the address bar /user_sessions/destroy, I get the following error:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for UserSessionsController
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `config/routes.rb`

```
match "user_sessions/destroy" => "user_sessions#destroy", via: [:get]
```

Assuming you have your `user_session` routes defined as a `resource` in your `config/routes.rb`, the `destroy` action's route requires the HTTP method be `DELETE` to `/user_sessions`, making a `GET` request to the *(non-existent)* `/user_sessions/destroy` route through the address bar of your browser fail.

The addition of the above route maps the `/user_sessions/destroy` path you're trying to access to load the `UserSessions` controller's `destroy` method instead of the *(non-existent)* `show` method, passing `"destroy"` as the `:id` param.

Comment: That made it work! Thanks :) Although I had to put this line before the resources :user_sessions line in my routes.rb

Comment: That's interesting; in my application that's not necessary (it's actually got a different route name altogether from the resource). Glad it's sorted out.